# How to initialize code in mounted hook instead of in individual methods?

Tags: vuejs2

I am learning how to use a Javascript image annotation library called [Annotoriou](https://github.com/recogito/annotorious)s. How can I initialize the library during the mounted hook (assuming that's the best place for it to happen) and not have it initialized in inidividual methods like the way I have it now?

I have two methods: **(working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-greider-ri1w7?file=/src/components/PhotoDetail.vue) )**

> PhotoDetail.vue

```
annotatePhoto() {
  try {
    const anno = new Annotorious({   <-------- how to get this out of this scope and into the global scope of this SFC?
      image: this.photo.id // image element or ID
    })
    // Attach listeners to handle annotation events
    anno.on('createAnnotation', annotation => {
      console.log('Created!', annotation)
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('anno error', error)
  }
}
```

and

```
loadAnnotations() {
const anno = new Annotorious({   <-------- how to get this out of this scope and into the global scope of this SFC?
      image: this.photo.id // image element or ID
    })
          anno.setAnnotations(annotations) < --- this is undefined because of this scope
        })
    }
```

I tried:

```
  computed: {
    anno() {
      const anno = Annotorious.init({
        image: this.photo.id
      })
      return anno
    }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Got it working. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get this to work:

```
  data() {
    return {
      photo: {},
      anno: {}
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.getPhoto()
    this.anno = new Annotorious({ image: this.photo.id })
    this.annotatePhoto()
```